# Usage of Float and Integer in DynaActionForm properties and retrieving them with struts-html.tld tags

Tags: forms, jsp, struts1

I have a DynaActionForm element in my struts-config.xml like:

```
<form-bean name="myActionForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
            <!-- Control Params -->
            <form-property name="action" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="list" type="java.lang.String" initial="master_document_list.data"/>
            <!--  Business params -->
            <form-property name="code" type="java.lang.String"/>            
            <form-property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <form-property name="description" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <form-property name="sequenceNumber" type="java.lang.Float"/>       
        </form-bean>
```

And the jsp page where I am trying to use it:

```
<!-- struts-html.tld imported with prefix html -->
<html:form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Sequence No.</td>
<td><html:text property="sequenceNumber" maxlength="15" style="width:75%"/></td>
</tr>
<table>
</html:form>
```

but when i do this I am getting a JspException saying "No getter method for property sequenceNumber. I am quite sure that the name is correct. Is it the type that is not getting accepted then? I thought the DynaActionForm allowed types are all major java types including the Thread-Safe Wrappers (e.g. Float, Integer, Short, Long, etc.).

N.B. I am using struts1

Answer (score 0):

After digging apache documentation, i figured out that

`<html:text>` tag has got the following settings:

name= Name of the form bean
property= Name of the property associated to the form-property tag for the bean above

Althernatively, using `${myBean.map.myProp}` will point me to the right direction.

Thanks all,